# bacterial growth curve (logistic/sigmoid) with multiple explanatory variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls, non-linear-regression

**Goal: I want to obtain regression (ggplot curves and model parameters) for growth curves with multiple treatments.**

I have data for bacterial cultures C={a,b,c,d} growing on nutrient sources N={x,y}.

Their idealized growth curves (measuring turbidity of cell culture every hour) look something like this:
[image]

There are 8 different curves to obtain coefficients and curves for. How can I do it in one go for my data frame, feeding the different treatments as different groups for the nonlinear regression?

Thanks!!!

This question is similar to an unanswered question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015299/fit-and-compare-multiple-sigmoid-curves-in-r).

(sourcecode for idealized data, sorry it's not elegant as I'm not a computer scientist):

```
a<-1:20
a[1]<-0.01
for(i in c(1:19)){
  a[i+1]<-1.3*a[i]*(1-a[i])
}
b<-1:20
b[1]<-0.01
for(i in c(1:19)){
  b[i+1]<-1.4*b[i]*(1-b[i])
}
c<-1:20
c[1]<-0.01
for(i in c(1:19)){
  c[i+1]<-1.5*c[i]*(1-c[i])
}
d<-1:20
d[1]<-0.01
for(i in c(1:19)){
  d[i+1]<-1.6*d[i]*(1-d[i])
}
sub.data<-cbind(a,b,c,d)
require(reshape2)
data<-melt(sub.data, value.name = "OD600")
data$nutrition<-rep(c("x", "y"), each=5, times=4)
colnames(data)[1:2]<-c("Time", "Culture")


ggplot(data, aes(x = Time, y = OD600, color = Culture, group=nutrition)) +
  theme_bw() + xlab("Time/hr") + ylab("OD600") +
  geom_point() +  facet_wrap(~nutrition, scales = "free")
```

Comment: You may want to check [Fitting a sigmoid curve in R](http://kyrcha.info/2012/07/08/tutorials-fitting-a-sigmoid-function-in-r/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar `group_by` function from `dplyr` (included in `tidyverse`), then you can group your data by Culture and nutrition and create models for each group using `broom`. I think this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html) is getting at exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Here is the code all in one go:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(mgcv)  #For the gam model

data %>%
      group_by(Culture, nutrition) %>%
      do(fit = gam(OD600 ~ s(Time), data = ., family=gaussian())) %>% # Change this to whatever model you want (e.g., non-linear regession, sigmoid)
      #do(fit = lm(OD600 ~ Time, data = .,)) %>% # Example using linear regression
      augment(fit) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = OD600, color = Culture)) + # No need to group by nutrition because that is broken out in the facet_wrap
      theme_bw() +  xlab("Time/hr") + ylab("OD600") +
      geom_point() + facet_wrap(~nutrition, scales = "free") +
      geom_line(aes(y = .fitted, group = Culture))
```

If you are ok without one go, break apart the `%>%` for better understanding. I used GAM which overfits here but you could replace this with whatever model you want, including sigmoid.

[image]